# filtering age of members using linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datetime

I am trying to check for people in a certain range - let minage and maxage corresponding for e.g. age group with minage=18 and  maxage =24 meaning I am trying to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24.Also datatype for dob of member is string ..

i am trying this

```
int agefrom = Convert.ToInt32(cbGEFrom.Text);
int ageto = Convert.ToInt32(cbGETo.Text);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime max = today.AddYears(-(agefrom + 1));
DateTime min = today.AddYears(-(ageto));
string maxage = Convert.ToString(max);
string minage = Convert.ToString(min);

var members = 
    from report in eclipse.members 
    where string.Compare(report.member_Dob,minage) >=0
    where string.Compare(report.member_Dob,maxage) < 0
    select report;
```

i dont know is this way is correct or not ..

would any pls suggest any idea ..

many thanks in advance...

Comment: why don't you test your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int agefrom = Convert.ToInt32(cbGEFrom.Text);
    int ageto = Convert.ToInt32(cbGETo.Text);

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime maxDOB = today.AddYears(-ageTo);
    DateTime minDOB = today.AddYears(-ageFrom);

    var members = eclipse.members.Where(m=>m.member_Dob>=minDOB && m.member_Dob<=maxDOB);
```

EDIT: Query comprehension is as under

```
    var members = from member in eclipse.members
                  where member.member_Dob>=minDOB && member.member_Dob<=maxDOB
                  select member;
```

Comment: would you pls suggest any solution with linq ......not using lambda expressions..

Comment: With LINQ and **not** using Lambda expressions?!

Comment: @errorcode105 added the query comprehension. Both are called linq btw.

Comment: @errorcode105: You should really learn to use LINQ with both styles - in this case, with just a `Where` clause, there's really no point in using a query expression.

Comment: @errorcode105 best way to thank is to accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: @jon skeet by default member_dob datatype is string unfortunatley i cannot change the schema..

Answer (score 2):

Comparing dates via their string value feels horridly wrong to me.

You say the type of the member_Dob field is `string`; I'd say there is something wrong with your model, it should be `DateTime`

If you can't change the underlying model, at least convert it in code (using `DateTime.Parse`). Then you can simply compare `DateTime`s in your where clause as per the other answers:

```
var members = from report in eclipse.members
          let dob =  DateTime.Parse(report.member_Dob) // or use ParseExact 
          where  dob >= minDOB && dob < maxDOB 
          select report;
```